# SQLite AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: java, android, sqlite

My table is created like this:

```
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE reminder (" +
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY_KEY AUTO_INCREMENT," +
            "title VARCHAR(100)," +
            "content VARCHAR(500)," +
            "due LONG," +
            "alarm LONG," +
            "priority INT" +
            ");");
```

and values inserted by:

```
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("title",t.title);
    cv.put("content",t.content);
    cv.put("due",t.date.getTimeInMillis());
    cv.put("alarm",(t.alarm==null?0L:t.alarm.getTimeInMillis()));
    cv.put("priority",t.severity);
    SQLiteDatabase d=getWritableDatabase();
    d.insert("reminder",null, cv);
    d.close();
```

But when I try to get my values by:

```
        Task task=new Task();
        task.id=c.getInt(0);
        task.title=c.getString(1);
        task.content=c.getString(2);
        Calendar due=new GregorianCalendar();
        due.setTimeInMillis(c.getLong(3));
        task.date=due;
        if(c.getLong(4)!=0){
            Calendar alert=new GregorianCalendar();
            alert.setTimeInMillis(c.getLong(4));
            task.alarm=alert;
        }
        task.severity=c.getInt(5);
        return task;
```

I get always id equal to zero. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1

Comment: Why my android sqlite has different syntax?

Comment: Btw, it changed nothing

Comment: Have you tried setting to null the id with cv.put()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underscores are a bit out of place.  Try `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`.

[SQL As Understood By SQLite - CREATE TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)

Comment: But probelm is that in OpenSQLHelper it doesnt work. Any idea why?

Comment: It turned out, that the problem could be caused by _ in id missin.

Comment: Ah yes, Android Adapters love their `_id`.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this solution:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE reminder (" +
            "'_id' INTEGER PRIMARY_KEY AUTO_INCREMENT," +
            "title VARCHAR(100)," +
            "content VARCHAR(500)," +
            "due LONG," +
            "alarm LONG," +
            "priority INT" +
            ");");
```

Changed id for _id.